# Vue js : How to get specific route parameter in url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a nested route settings

```
let routes = [
{
    name: 'Admin',
    path: '/prod/:id',
    component: Admin,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        title: 'Admin - Fraud tool'
    },
    children:[
        {
            path: 'users',
            component: Users
        }
    ]
}];
```

Then my url looks like this

```
http://localhost/prod/admin/users
```

How can I get the `admin` in this route in vue js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `$route.params.id` or `$route.params` which will give you object result

https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html